# Unexpected behavior of Structure in C

Tags: c, struct, scanf, turbo-c++

I have written the following code in C programming (using Turbo c++).

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test
{
   char fname[10];
   char age[2];
   char lname[10];
}s1[10];

int main()
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
     printf("enter the first name : ");
     scanf("%s",s1[i].fname);
     printf("enter the last name : ");
     scanf("%s",s1[i].lname);
     printf("enter the age : ");
     scanf("%s",s1[i].age);
   }
   for(i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
     printf("\n %s %s age= %s",s1[i].fname,s1[i].lname,s1[i].age);
   }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I have entered inputs as asked for. But the last name (lname) was found missing when the result printed.

Can you help me solve this unexpected behavior of structure. (Kindly neglect the value [10], age declared as string etc as I did it for my own purpose)

Kindly note: when I declared the age as ' `int` ' and used `%d` the lastname was displayed, but when all were  declared character it is not working.

Comment: hope that you're code isn't written actually that way... No indentation :(

Comment: @DonCallisto consider the above program to input 3 persons name( first name, last name) and their age.

Comment: this is a good interview sample :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char age[2];` is way too small. If you input exactly 2 characters, `scanf` will write the termination string into `lname[0]` because in this specific case the memory between both arrays is contiguous.

Thus `printf` will see an empty array and the result will be the one you observe

Comment: Better use a bigger number like 8, for safety. You will still run into this issue for malicious input. If you want a robust code, add fields between your buffers to detect overflow.

Comment: @UmNyobe Keep in mind that `scanf` should be avoided anyway. It has no idea of the buffer size it may use. Use `fgets` instead. A larger number is no safety at all. It's just more difficult to experience the bug when you enter a long string and press ^H^H... after that.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char age[2];
```

to

```
char age[4];
```

Strings need additional space for the terminating null character.

Comment: thank you. I changed to age[3] no one i know is 100+ :) thank you

Comment: I have upvoted ur answer. accepting the above as he answered 1st, Thaank u

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, as others have pointed out, that you have a buffer overflow on  `scanf`.

**How to fix:**

Solution is **not** to only increase buffer sizes. Solution is to prevent overflow altogether.

Increase buffer sizes:

```
char age[3+1]; /* 3 for digits, +1 for NUL char */
```

Specify maximum chars to read:

```
scanf("%3s", s1[i].age);
```

But since you read only strings, I would recommend using `fgets` instead:

```
fgets( s1[i].age, 4, stdin);
```

Do this for all fields. And even better: use constants for buffer sizes.

Answer (score 0):

the new line character will be inserted as second input for scanf(); i.e: your input for s1 and s2 are: 
test1 
test2
then s1= "test1" and s2="\n"

so in your case you should use gets() function instead of scanf(). and your string size will be number of characters you want to input plus 1 because every string will add additional terminating character('\0') at the end. i.e: if you want to input 5 character in char s1[SIZE]; then SIZE must be 6. follow these instructions. hope it will help for this issue to fix up. or you can run this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test
{
    char fname[10];
    char age[3]; // for maximum 2 digits
    char lname[10];
} s1[10];

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("enter the first name : ");
        gets(s1[i].fname);
        printf("enter the last name : ");
        gets(s1[i].lname);
        printf("enter the age : ");
        gets(s1[i].age);
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %s %s age= %s",s1[i].fname,s1[i].lname,s1[i].age);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```